# What would be the simplest way to manage states of form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, object

I have multiple drop-down lists, all contain the same options
I need to make it so that every item can be selected only on one list (if I select the color red on one list, it is grayed-out on all the rest)
and if the item is un-selected it's siblings are un-grayed

all lists have a default blank option which of course can be selected on all lists, but the lists populated from the server so there is no constant default option.

I started with simple `if`s but when the amount of the `if`s grew ridiculously big I realized I need a better way, some kind of structure that will constantly mirror the state of the list.

I am not sure how to do it and I am looking direction/pattern/framework

Comment: You should use a framework or plug in that allows you to [`observe`](https://gist.github.com/1928176) the dropdowns

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe thanx, but the events part is easier, what troubles me is how to keep the data of the state of the lists so that when I make changes I won't have to go over all the DOM and check lots of `if`s

Comment: angularjs (http://angularjs.org/) perhaps?

Comment: @akonsu tahnx, angular seems way overkill for a bunch of lists..

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that instead of making drop down lists reference to data source, make data source items reference drop down lists.
i.e. each item has a property named `relatedDropDown`.
so available items for each drop down would be items that their `relatedDropDown` is null or is equal to its own. 
when a drop down's value is changes, the selected values property should be set to the drop down (and of coarse if it had an old value, the old item's property should be set null), and all other drop downs should be re-bound.